# Get user uid in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to filter my user from a list of users in the recycler view. But I need to get the uid for each user inside the onBindViewHolder and I don't know how. I'd also like to move the code in onBindViewHolder to the bind method of the ViewHolder but I don't know how to get the context.

[Here is what I've done](https://pastebin.com/nryL3rS9)

```
private void setRecyclerView() {
    mUsersRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new UserAdapter();
    mUsersRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> list = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            // Filter current user
            //List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot user : list) {
                if (!user.getKey().equals(mCurrentUid)) {
                    mUserList.add(user.getValue(User.class));
                }
            }
            // Setting data
            // mAdapter.setItems(userList);
        }

        @Override public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}

private class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = mUserList.get(position);
        holder.bind(user);

        // TODO: move this to holder.bind() method
        holder.setThumb_image(user.getThumb_image(),getApplicationContext());
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent9 = new Intent(UsersActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                intent9.putExtra("user_id", uid); // TODO: get uid for each user here
                startActivity(intent9);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUserList.size();
    }
}

private class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void bind(User user) {
        TextView nameView = mView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        nameView.setText(user.getName());

        TextView statusView = mView.findViewById(R.id.item_status);
        statusView.setText(user.getStatus());
    }

    public void setThumb_image(String thumb_image, Context ctx) {
        CircleImageView imageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.mipmap.icon).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

[Here is a working code](https://pastebin.com/b2LmbmiP) with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that doesn't filter the user.

Comment: You are trying ti filter your user from a list of users based on what condition?

Comment: If the uid of the user in the list is the same as the uid of the current logged user, that user isn't added to the list.

Comment: So you are trying to create a list inside the `onBindViewHolder` method? Why? That method is used to bind views not to create lists.

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder` I just want to bind the view to each item of the list, but I need the uid to open the profile of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add firbaseId in your model while you store data to firebase database

Here's example user model class which stores user's information to firebase

```
public class User {
private String name;
private String address;
private String firebaseId;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getFirebaseId() {
    return firebaseId;
}

public void setFirebaseId(String firebaseId) {
    this.firebaseId = firebaseId;
}
```

}

And then store value like below

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(DATABASE_NAME);
    String fireBaseId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    if (fireBaseId != null) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("SSB");
        user.setAddress("Some address");
        user.setFirebaseId(fireBaseId);
        databaseReference.child(fireBaseId).setValue(user);
    }
```

Then you can get id from user model class

Comment: This works great although it won't work for the currently logged users, maybe there is a way of passing the uid with the list? A map or something.

Comment: You can store currently logged in user id in session using shared preferences refer this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences, and then use that id